# strange bug with drawing in UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, drawing, uinavigationbar, core-graphics, uistackview

I'm trying to make screen with view in which user can draw something. I created custom view with such code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)
        drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        // draw a single point
        drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
```

and drawing function

```
func drawLine(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height))

    context?.move(to: fromPoint)
    context?.addLine(to: toPoint)

    context?.setLineCap(.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)

    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

when I show that view in view controller all is normal:

[image]

but when I show it in detail view in UISplitViewController, while user continue drawing, part of already drew image moving and fading out:
[image]

I can't find anything about what bug in web and have no idea what is produced such behaviour

Is anybody have any ideas about that?

That is example project where you can reproduce that bug:
https://github.com/fizzy871/DrawingBug

btw, in real project not only master view of split view controller, but navigation bar affect drawing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that it behaves such way because of imageView frame with fractional part in size.

[image]

I just multiplied drawing context by 2 and problem solved:

```
func drawLine(fromPoint fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
    // multiply to avoid problems when imageView frame value is XX.5
    let fixedFrameForDrawing = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.size.width*2, height: imageView.frame.size.height*2)
    let point1 = CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x*2, y: fromPoint.y*2)
    let point2 = CGPoint(x: toPoint.x*2, y: toPoint.y*2)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(fixedFrameForDrawing.size)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        imageView.image?.draw(in: fixedFrameForDrawing)

        context.move(to: point1)
        context.addLine(to: point2)

        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth*2)
        context.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)

        context.strokePath()

        let imageFromContext = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        imageView.image = imageFromContext
    }
```

Comment: This just happened in my app, crazy stuff. Now I rounded down the frame size and it works fine. It must have been hard to figure out, thanks for the solution!